# problem with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm beginner in jquery.this is my first application.

```
<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type=”text/javascript”>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function(){
        alert("Hello World");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href=”#”>Click me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i click on `Click me` the alert doesn't showed.what is problem?
(the lib address(`src="../jquery-1.6.2.min.js`) is correct )

Comment: Have you checked firebug to make totally sure that your jquery lib is loading?

Comment: Your JQuery code isn't probably being loaded.

Comment: It works for me..with you code..The only change i did is that <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have odd quotes in some of your code:

`”` vs. `"`

That could be causing your problem.  Change them all over to regular double quotes `"`

EDIT: Tested it, it's the funny quotes around `text/javascript` specifically but the other should be fixed too.

Answer (score 2):

That works fine! check the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PdpWR/

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you either have a problem with your reference to jQuery or with the weird quotes around your `#` and `text/javascript`.

I took your code and placed it in jsfiddle and it runs fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/PZxjV/

Are you sure that you have the correct location for your jQuery file?